# Make files which starts with a dot visible for every user

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, file-permissions, dropbox

I'm trying to delete an uploaded Dropbox directory, but only receive "550 Access Denied" and i don't know why. I already tried to set the directory permissions to 777 but nothing changed.

On the other hand, my delete command can clear the complete Dropbox directory, except the folders itself. (Every file in the shared directories can be deleted)

This is my structure before delete command:

- root

  - Dropbox

    - Folder1 (S)

      - Folder1.1
      - Folder1.2
      - Folder1.3
    - Folder2 (P)

      - ...
    - Folder3 (S)

      - .dropbox (i)
      - File3.1
      - File3.2
      - File3.3
    - Folder4 (P)
    - File1 (P)
    - File2 (P)
    - File3 (P)
    - File4 (P)

(S) = Shared Directory

(P) = Private Directory

(i) = Invisible

And this is my structure after the command:

- root

  - Dropbox

    - Folder1

      - Folder1.3
    - Folder3

      - .dropbox (i)

Could someone explain this?

My Server using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS as OS and vsftp for FTP connections

My Client using Windows 7 32 Bit and my Application was created with VB 2010

**EDIT1:**

I found, that every directory contains a file which starts with a dot `.`.

Linux don't list this files and the user get the response "Empty Folder". Even with `dir` command Linux return nothing. Only with `ls -a` Linux is showing the remaining files.

Now my Question: Is there any way, how i can change the visibility of this files for FTP Users to visible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deleted everything anyway, can't you just run `rm -R Dropbox`? This will remove everything recursively, including files/directories starting with `.`.

As for FTP users seeing those files, I think it really depends on the actual FTP server being used (and possibly the client as well).

Comment: Yes, rm -r works fine, but how should i do this via my FTP client?

Comment: You might not be able to do so, but as said, this really depends on the FTP client. For example, I'm using WinSCP and it shows me files such as `.htaccess` just fine (but greyed out). I remember Windows Explorer not doing that when viewing an FTP server. A tiny "hack" for single dotted files: Upload a file with the same name and delete it immediately. This will work in some clients (like Windows Explorer), but I'm aware that this is no solution for the long run.

Comment: Ok, i downloaded WinSCP and found this folders. Now i mus show, how i could implement this into my application :/ Thanks for your help.